# Why isn't TypeScript checking assignment types or undefined when assigning from an object lookup

Tags: typescript, typechecking

```
type Whatever = {
  name: string;
};
const map: { [key: string]: Whatever } = {};

// Errors
const a: Whatever = {}; // name is required in type Whatever
const b: Whatever = undefined; // undefined not assignable

// No Errors
const c: Whatever = map["not-found"]; // undefined
const d: Whatever = map["not-found"] || {}; // {}
```

Or take a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gFgQ2BAbhATlAvFA3gKCigDsEBbCALigGdh0BLYgcwG58BfdgYwHti6UMgjDVcUANoBrCCGp1GLALrV4SVBigdseLvnwB6A1ACi6dL3Q18fAcCgJViZGkw5cXKEZLloDGlDoEACOAK4MQQAmUExQoJCwzhroNvyCAEZO6q46ocSREABmTBCRrF7GeQXFxKUkvPYINDQMzKTpADYQ+t4Acrym5pbWtoLcWS6aOMJgEgBExA0AtIW8VXNK5d5VRSWRqXZQkRPJOjPzi8Ara-kbUAA+97pbxh74QA)

I'd expect assignment of `c` and `d` to fail type-checking.

Answer (score 1):

Your code behaves correctly if your map contains `Whatever | undefined`. It does do type-checking; you have simply told it that `map` contains a Whatever instance for any `key: string`.

```
const map: { [key: string]: Whatever | undefined } = {};
```

Of course, there are infinite possible string keys, so you can't have a value defined for all of them, but you've declared your type that way and Typescript isn't going to correct you.

Comment: I think that needs to be `Whatever | undefined`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You've discovered that index signatures in TypeScript aren't completely type safe.  For a type with an index signature like this:

```
interface Indexable {
    [k: string]: string;
}
```

the compiler does the following mutually-inconsistent things: properties are optional (possibly absent) when assigning a value to the type:

```
const i: Indexable = {}; // no error
```

but they are viewed as required (definitely present) when indexing into the type:

```
i.oops.toUpperCase(); // no error but explodes at runtime
```

Consistency would require that its properties be considered either required or optional.  Considering all `string`-keyed properties to be required would be crazy, since you'd never be able to assign any normal objects to such a type... so let's forget that.

Considering all properties of an index signature as if they were optional is less crazy, and it would be consistent.  So, your question: **why doesn't the compiler do it that way?**

---

If there is a canonical answer to this, it's in [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778), a suggestion that index signature properties be considered as possibly `undefined`, as if the `Indexable` above were written like this:

```
interface SafeIndexable {
    [k: string]: string | undefined;
}
const s: SafeIndexable = {}; // no error
s.oops.toUpperCase(); // error, Object is possibly undefined.
```

It's an open issue, so there's some slim chance it might eventually be supported with a compiler flag (`--strictIndexChecks`?).  But the TS team doesn't really think this is a good way to go, because it would be **very annoying to use**.

If you have a `SafeIndexable`:

```
const t: SafeIndexable = { a: "hey", b: "you", c: "there" };
```

you can't iterate over its properties as if they exist:

```
console.log(Object.keys(t).map(k => t[k].toUpperCase()).join(" ")); // error!
// -------------------------------> ~~~~
// Object is possibly undefined
```

Instead, you'd have to either do a superfluous runtime check, or use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (`!`) to circumvent the error because you *know* you're being safe:

```
console.log(Object.keys(t).map(k => t[k]!.toUpperCase()).join(" ")); // okay now
```

And the argument is that this would happen in so many cases, especially with arrays, and that developers would get so used to disabling the check, that when they actually *do* make a mistake and write dangerous code, they'd just suppress the error the same way:

```
const u: SafeIndexable = { d: "uh", e: "oh" };
console.log(Object.keys(u).map(k =>
    t[k]!.toUpperCase()).join(" ")); // no error but explodes at runtime!
```

The type system just doesn't have enough information about indexable types to usefully warn you about when you are likely to be doing unsafe things and not warn you when you are likely to be doing safe things.  And so you can choose between lots of false negatives or lots of false positives, and at least false negatives are *quiet*.

See [this comment by Ryan Cavanaugh](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778#issuecomment-286859503) for the full argument for why it's like this.  A highlight:

> I think of the old "Are you sure you want to delete this file?" dialog. If that dialog appeared every time you tried to delete a file, you would very quickly learn to hit `del`  `y` when you used to hit `del`, and your chances of not deleting something important reset to the pre-dialog baseline. If instead the dialog only appeared when you were deleting files when they weren't going to the recycling bin, now you have meaningful safety. But we have no idea (nor *could* we) whether your object keys are safe or not, so showing the "Are you sure you want to index that object?" dialog every time you do it isn't likely to find bugs at a better rate than not showing it all.

---

So that's the current situation.  If you're writing your own indexable types and you want to get more type safety in exchange for less ease of use, you can always add `| undefined` yourself as in `SafeIndexable` above.  In most cases in my experience, the added type safety isn't worth it, except for some less common situations in which I expect to use unsafe keys.  But your mileage may vary.

Okay, hope that helps. Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgCYQB5wEYA2KA3gLABQyVyA2gNYBcyAzmFKAOYC6Tr7IHANwUAvhQoIA9iFbJgTdFlyEUAXmTERg5AHodyEJOTQokqBWAA6SZIAOzS2EkBVW7egBhOMwgAKAJTaegZGJmbIeACuYMbYtgSSWMzIcDFQkeDAALYQ4uSgkLCIKADKcDAQijj4RBoU1LSMLGycPM38HMgAPsgZWDCgEBjC5GLkUjIxzExlFVXKteqaQfqGxlCm5uQONvaOLm6e3n6BuvphUAA0yADyeABWEAgxwMm2kszMwIQAnr2YEAGICGljyE1kYBm5UqAIWag0KSYACIABYQH5I654ZE-SSRTHIBDIsBoqAQJHILT1CTSZiSIiWBIcXx3R7PSx0dHMXxgfyWLJwWy+OjIVQAPmQYHoXH2rncUC8PgCfPuklAvgpSP8p2CFwAhBRggBaE2ms3mi2W00SgB+dpthv0rKeLzeHy+v3+-UGGDBtPpEEZkmZzvZnJ+3N5-MFwtFEqldC4etlhwVx2VllV6s12pWyEkdDgPz9k16ULmsJq8OIyAwyMiKIJEGRkkblJG4IDQZDDxdHK5vkifIFQpF4vq1ATSZT8sVJxVapAGuQWp1q1CG3CURiOHiiQgyVSyHSmRyeqAA)